# (React) How to match the modal content with the clicked element?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-modal

I'm trying to match the modal that shows with the clicked element, right now i'm rendering all the modals with the click,  I been trying to make them match with the index but no luck , please help.

here are my constructors

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        portfolioData: [],
        newModal:[],
        modalPost: false,
        isShown: false
    };
} 

showModal = (i) =>{        
    this.setState({ isShown: true, modalPost: true })
} 

closeModal = () => {
    this.setState({isShown:false, modalPost: false})
}
```

and here I get the data and render two list component and the modal

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`data.json`)
        .then(res => {
            const portfolioData = [res.data.portfolio.projects.film];
            this.setState({ portfolioData });                  
        })
};
```

the components

```
const portfolioList = this.state.portfolioData.map((value) => 
    value.map((val, idx) =>             
        <PortfolioItem 
            id={val.title.en.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}
                title={val.title.en}
                imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                status={val.status}
                profile={val.profile}
                director={val.director}
                production={val.production}
                showModal={this.showModal}
                youtube={val.trailer}
            />
))

const modalList = this.state.portfolioData.map((value) => 
    value.map((val, idx) =>             
        <Modal
            id={val.title.en.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}
            title={val.title.en}
            imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
            status={val.status}
            profile={val.profile}
            director={val.director}
            production={val.production}
            closeModal={this.closeModal}
            youtube={val.trailer}
        />                
    ))
```

and the return

```
<section id="portfolio">                      
    { portfolioList }
    { this.state.modalPost !== false ? modalList : null }                
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will make as many modal as the data held by `this.state.portfolioData`, which is unnecessary, inefficient and may result into wasted rendering. If you take a step back and think from this way, **You are going to render only one modal but render it with the data of the selected item**

Lets see an example,

We can start by having an additional state value `selectedValue` which will hold the clicked item's value

```
this.state = {
  portfolioData: [],
  newModal:[],
  modalPost: false,
  isShown: false,
  selectedValue: {}  //<---
};
```

Then, when the user clicks the item we can set that particular items value in the state; specifically in `selectedValue`

```
const portfolioList = this.state.portfolioData.map((value) => 
    value.map((val, idx) =>             
        <PortfolioItem 
            id={val.title.en.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}
                title={val.title.en}
                imgsrc={val.imgsrc}
                status={val.status}
                profile={val.profile}
                director={val.director}
                production={val.production}
                showData={() => this.showData(val)}   //<---
                youtube={val.trailer}
            />
))

//new function for one specific task   <---
const showData = (value) => {
  this.setState({selectedValue: value}, this.showModal)
}
```

Finally, instead of mapping over the data you can render only one modal which takes and show the data from the `this.state.selectedValue`

```
<Modal
 id={this.state.selectedValue.title.en.toString().toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-")}
 title={this.state.selectedValue.title.en}
 imgsrc={this.state.selectedValue.imgsrc}
 status={this.state.selectedValue.status}
 profile={this.state.selectedValue.profile}
 director={this.state.selectedValue.director}
 production={this.state.selectedValue.production}
 closeModal={this.closeModal}
 youtube={this.state.selectedValue.trailer}
/>
```

This is merely an idea you can follow. You should organize/optimize your code later per your codebase afterwards. If you are unfamiliar with `setState`s second parameter it takes a callback as a second parameter which it executes after updating state. Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Hope this helps you, Cheers!

Edit: I just noticed you are not using that `isShown` anywhere. That is the value that the modal should be opened based on. The modal should have a prop which makes it show/hide by passing true/false, check the documentation. And you should pass `this.state.isShown` to that specific prop to make everything come together and work!

Comment: my brother you are the best! it worked perfectly, and the tip for passing a second parameter on the setState is a great help as well.

Comment: @JSMITH glad to know. Please consider accepting the answer and upvote if it came to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating multiple instances of modals when you are looping over your *portfolioData*. I dont think you need the multiple instances since you will open only one at a time.

When you are setting the state of modal to *isShown*. You are actually setting state on all the instances of the generated modals. Hence you end up opening multiple modals. You should ideally have just one modal and pass data to your modal.

You can do this:

First, Move the modal out of the loop so that you have only one instance of it.

Pass data to:

```
 <a>onClick={() => this.toggleModal(provider.data)} key={index}>Portfolio Item</a>
```

Lastly, in toggleModal function first set the data then open modal.

This way all your PortfolioItem links will end up calling the same modal instance. But with different data. Once you set the data you can rerender your component with the already existing isShown state.

Here is a small example:
This way all your PortfolioItem links will end up calling the same modal instance. But with different data. Once you set the data you can rerender your component with the already existing *isShown* state.

Here is a small example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isShown: false,
      data: ''
    }
    this.list = [{data: 'data1'}, {data: 'data2'}];
  }

  onAnchorClick({data},event){
    this.setState({data, isShown: true});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.list.map((obj, idx) => <div key={idx}>
          <a onClick={this.onAnchorClick.bind(this, obj)}>Portfolio Item</a>
        </div>)}

        <div style={{display: !this.state.isShown ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
          <h3>Data: {this.state.data}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```